# Is it possible to get the long, lat, and alt of the sender of an SMS?

Tags: android, android-location

Can the longitude, latitude, and altitude of the sender of an SMS be ascertained in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you have some way of pinging the sender's phone - an sms is basically two parts: the message itself, and the phone number of the sender. There's no location data included with it, and definiteley no gps coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not; for a start, most mobile phones don't have GPS receivers.

Comment: That's not the only way to get location—there is also triangulation based on cell towers. Most handsets (in the US at least) should be able to do this (or ask the network to) due to E911 requirements. I'd guess Europe has similar requirements, but I don't know.

Comment: That's a good point; I was assuming all the callers to my app would be running an Android smartphone (and I will be using cell tower location, not GPS, for location info), but in actuality it could be a regular/dumb phone. Thanks for the reality check.

Answer (score 1):

Although there appears to be limited information on the topic, you should look into Silent SMS.  It does not appear to be what you are asking but it's an interesting topic.  There appear to be reports that these messages can be used by a telcom to obtain positional details.

Comment: Dubious; the operator already knows what cell a subscriber is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily encode all those coordinates in an SMS but they are not there by default. First, SMS'es' were developed at a time when we didn't have smart phones. Second, it would be a terrible privacy issue if you could.